# PostgreSQL - Is it possible to parallelize an UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql

I am running an UPDATE that affects millions of rows and it's pretty time consuming.  Is there a way to parallelize this in PostgreSQL?

I researched this and found nothing, but I have a couple of ideas I'm swinging at.

1) Will PostgreSQL do this automatically?  If yes, then great.

2) If PostgreSQL doesn't support this, it is possible to open up multiple concurrent connections and perform the UPDATES in parallel, but make sure the UPDATES don't affect the same rows (no overlapping data shared between queries)?   My worry is that PostgreSQL forces every UPDATE to be an atomic transaction and won't allow concurrent updates even if they affect different rows.  Is my worry correct?

Thanks in advance, James.

Comment: No, DML can currently not use parallel execution. 2) will definitely work

Comment: PostgreSQL has been adding parallelism execution of queries in recent versions. While I'm not sure this applies to updates, there's good reason to believe that it does (out at least can). https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/how-parallel-query-works.html

Comment: Why not just benchmark on your scenario, always a good idea with perf questions? An ANALYZE may also shed some light on how your SQL is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My worry is that PostgreSQL forces every UPDATE to be an atomic
>   transaction and won't allow concurrent updates even if they affect
>   different rows.

Let's test

```
create table test(
id int,
name text
);

insert into test
values
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'b');
```

Then run this transaction:

```
do $$
begin
    update test set
    name  = 'aa'
    where id = 1;

    perform pg_sleep(15);
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

and then run this one, as another transaction

```
do $$
begin
    update test set
    name  = 'bb'
    where id = 2;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Second transactions runs immediately, while first one still running.